# How to load address in cart.phtml

Tags: magento2, cart

How can I load **all addresses** and **address form** on cart page ?

I tried the bellow code but it doesn't work !

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/shipping.phtml" >

    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: what you have tried except this. can you please share some code which you have try  to display form and address

Answer (score 1):

To get your current customer address in cart :

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart.phtml

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerId = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();

if ($customerId){
    $customerObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);
    foreach($customerObject->getAddresses() as $customerAddress){
        echo $customerAddress['street'];
        echo $customerAddress['postcode'];
        echo $customerAddress['city'];
    }

    //For default billing address
    $defaultBilling = $customerObject->getDefaultBilling();
    $address = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Address')->load($defaultBilling);
    \Zend_Debug::dump($address->debug());
}
```

**Note :** You have here your customer address, you can do it more better by **rewriting** that file `cart.phtml` in your **module** then you use a `dependency injection` in your **block** to avoid the **object manager** in template like my solution.

Comment: I want to show all address and address form like checkout

Comment: All customer address ? yes look to my `foreach`code, it loops on all addresses

Comment: and where is address form?

Comment: I didn't understand your need, address form ? there is no address form you have to contruct it, if you want some dop down with the multiples addresses, you have to include <select> before the foreach and <option> inside each address

Answer (score 0):

Seems that we have the data already: `window.checkoutConfig.customerData` on cart and checkout pages.

[image]